# Calculating Mehta integral using induction.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I was wondering if there is a way to compute the Mehta integral for real numbers by using induction or some nice reverse engineering with Laplace transform, or if this is vain.
Here $\gamma$ is real

$$
\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n / 2}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cdots \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-t_i^2 / 2} \prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq n}\left|t_i-t_j\right|^{2 \gamma} d t_1 \cdots d t_n=\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{\Gamma(1+j \gamma)}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)}
$$
**Update**: I want to inform that instead of requiring $\gamma$ to be real, now I want $\gamma$ to be a positive integer. Now any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Even for the case $n = 2$, it's already hard. and Mathematica shows that $\gamma \in \mathbb{N}$ (for the case $n = 2$), perhaps it's also the solution for the general case.

Comment: how about replacing the $t_i - t_j$ terms with a generating term $e^{-\lambda_{ij}(t_i-t_j)^2}$ and then expand in the lambdas

Comment: then what can be after that?

Comment: the gaussian s can be evaluated, so you can get closed form epressions for all powers of lambda

Comment: Can you add more if possible, Thank you

Comment: This is $\Bbb E(Z^\gamma)$ where $Z=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(X_i-X_j)^2$, for some i.i.d standard normal $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Long Comment.** Here is a proof for $n = 2$:

> **Lemma.** For $0 < \operatorname{Re}(\gamma) < 1$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, define
>
> \begin{align*}
> C_{\gamma}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos(ax)}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x
> \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> E_{\gamma}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-ax^2}}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x.
> \end{align*}
>
> Then we have
>
> $$C_{\gamma}(a) = C_{\gamma}(1) |a|^{2\gamma}
> \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> E_{\gamma}(a) = \frac{\Gamma(1+2\gamma)}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)}C_{\gamma}(1) |a|^{\gamma}. $$

We postpone the proof of this lemma to the end. Using this, we can proceed as follow:

Clearly, the Mehta integral is an analytic function in $\gamma$. In light of the principle of analytic continuation, it suffices to prove that the equality holds for $0 < \gamma < 1$. Then, denoting by $I_n$ the Metha integral,

\begin{align*}
I_2
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |t_1 - t_2|^{2\gamma} e^{-(t_1^2 + t_2^2)/2} \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \mathrm{d}t_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi C_{\gamma}(1)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos((t_1 - t_2)x)}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) e^{-(t_1^2 + t_2^2)/2} \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \mathrm{d}t_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi C_{\gamma}(1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{Re}\biggl( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t_1^2 + t_2^2)/2} [1 - e^{it_1 x}e^{-it_2 x}] \, \mathrm{d}t_1 \mathrm{d}t_2 \biggr) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \\
&= \frac{1}{C_{\gamma}(1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-x^2}) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(1+2\gamma)}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)}.
\end{align*}

In the intermediate steps, we utilized the lemma and the identity $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ixt} e^{-t^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-x^2/2}$. $\square$

I am currently testing whether this technique can be extended to larger $n$'s, either by a direct computation or by an induction.

---

*Proof of Lemma.* It is clear that $C_{\gamma}(-a) = C_{\gamma}(a)$ and $C_{\gamma}(0) = 0$. For $a > 0$, substituting $ax \mapsto x$ immediately proves the first identity.

For the second identity, a similar trick shows $E_{\gamma}(a) = E_{\gamma}(1)|a|^{\gamma}$, hence it suffices to establish the equality when $a = 1$. However,

\begin{align*}
E_{\gamma}(1)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-x^2}}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{2 x^{1+\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{$x^2 \mapsto x$} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{2} \biggl( \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\gamma}e^{-xt} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1+\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\gamma} \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-x})e^{-xt} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1+\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{\gamma-1}}{t+1} \, \mathrm{d}t,
\end{align*}

and similarly,

\begin{align*}
C_{\gamma}(1)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x^{1+2\gamma}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{2} \biggl( \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+2\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{2\gamma}e^{-xt} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+2\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{2\gamma} \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - \cos x)e^{-xt} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+2\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2\gamma-1}}{t^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1+2\gamma)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{\gamma-1}}{t+1} \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{$t^2 \mapsto t$}
\end{align*}

Therefore the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: This is incredible...